# Get Data in one SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

My aim is easy, But I Don't know if I could retrieve my Data in one SQL query.

I have a table containing 4 columns the first holds some amounts to pay and the last is the installment's ID. I want, for a given amount get all the installments that I can pay.

For example (using the table below) if I have an amount = **2800** I want to get the 3 first rows (500/2000/2000) because I would pay 500 for the first, 2000 for the second and 300 for the third.

[image]

So is it possible to get desired rows in only one query ? I use SQL Server.

EDITED :

let's say the Amount that I have is **2800**

**The question**, which installments will I pay with that amount ?

**Response** : I would pay the 3 installments with ID's 136 / 135 and 134.

1. first I have 2800 so I can pay the first 500
2. second I have 2300 left So I can pay the second 2000
3. third I have 300 left  so I can pay the third 2000 (and 1700 still remain unpaid)

Thanks.

Comment: More clarification please. Tell something logical on how to get first three rows for amount 2800. I mean on what basis?

Comment: so basically "use up" whatever amount you have to pay off those balances?

Comment: What is the order things should get payed?

Comment: @PareshJ Calrification added EDITED Section

Comment: @MarcB I tried to use Up but the number to use I have to calculate it based on what I have as amount and how much should I pay depending ont the InstallmentPaiedAmount

Comment: Why wouldn't you pay those with an earlier EndInstallment first?  so 2000 on ID 133 then 800 on ID 134? @frlan question is very relevant.

Comment: @xQbert Because I want to begin with the last Installment and so on, this is why The Installments IDs are ordered by DESC

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to want a cumulative sum.  If you are using SQL Server 2012+, then this is easy:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, sum(col1) over (order by installmenthiddenid desc) as cumesum
      from table t
     ) t
where cumesum - col1 <= 2800;
```

I am making guesses about the column names and how you are defining the ordering.

In earlier versions of SQL Server, you can do the same thing with `apply` or a correlated subquery.

EDIT:

In SQL Server 2008, you would do:

```
select t.*
from table t cross apply
     (select t2.*, sum(t2.col1) as cumesum
      from table t2
      where t2.installmenthiddenid >= t.installmenthiddenid
     ) t2
where t2.cumesum - t.col1 <= 2800;
```

Comment: I am Using SQL SERVER 2008

Answer (score 1):

Try this. Find Running total using `Self join`.

```
;WITH cte
     AS (SELECT Sum(b.amount) - 2800 AS amnt,
                a.installpaidamount,
                a.endinstallment,
                a.installhiddenid
         FROM   Yourtable a
                JOIN Yourtable b
                  ON b.endinstallment >= a.endinstallment
         GROUP  BY a.installpaidamount,
                a.endinstallment,
                a.installhiddenid),
     cte2
     AS (SELECT TOP 1 *
         FROM   cte
         WHERE  amnt > 0
         ORDER  BY amnt) SELECT *
FROM   cte
WHERE  amnt < 0
UNION ALL
SELECT *
FROM   cte2
```